# Is it possible to enforce, at compile time, that two derived classes would always return different values for an overriding function?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual, constexpr, c++20

Is it possible to enforce, at compile time, that the following is acceptable:

```
class B {
public:
    virtual constexpr const char* getKeyStr() const = 0;
};

class D1 : public B {
public:
    constexpr const char* getKeyStr() const override { return "D1"; }
};

class D2 : public B {
public:
    constexpr const char* getKeyStr() const override { return "D2"; }
};
```

... But the following is not? We don't want `D1` and `D2` to return the same key string:

```
class B {
public:
    virtual constexpr const char* getKeyStr() const = 0;
};

class D1 : public B {
public:
    constexpr const char* getKeyStr() const override { return "D1"; }
};

class D2 : public B {
public:
    constexpr const char* getKeyStr() const override { return "D1"; } // can we error out here at compile time?
};
```

Clarifications:

1. I am only showing two derived classes in this example, but what I am trying to achieve is to post this constraint on any number of derived classes.
2. The underlying problem to solve: I am thinking about a serializing/deserializing application, where each object with the same base class will be able to generate a textual/string representation of itself to be written to a file and, when given that string back (let's call it the content-string), will be able to reconstruct the corresponding data.

   During deserialization, the application code should be able to tell from a key part of the content-string, let's call it the key-string, what derived object should be reconstructed. Therefore, the key-string needs to be unique for each derived class. I know `type_info::name` could be unique, but it is not customizable (or compiler independent?).
3. Regarding the `getKeyStr()` function (corresponding to the key-string mentioned above), it should always return the same string for all objects of the same derived class.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that no.

Comment: For a specific pair of classes `D1` and `D2`, or for all overrides of `B::getKeyStr()`?

Comment: This seems kind of anti-OO (not judging, mind you). In particular, it's goes against extensibility. What if I want to extend `D1` by deriving from it? Would a `class D3 : public D1` be forced to identify itself with a different `getKeyStr()`? Depending on what you're doing, a `std::variant` seems like it would be a better idea.

Comment: I'm more curious about why you want something like this? What is the actual and underlying problem that you try to solve? Why do you think something like this is the only solution to that problem? What other solutions have you considered?

Comment: Shouldn't `getKeyStr` be `static`? then with `tuple` to list all derived classes to check, it might be possible.

Comment: For a unique value for each class, you might want to consider [UUID's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), possibly generated using the name of the class (easily done using macros).

Comment: @Jarod42, I want to force every derived class to implement their own `getKeyStr()`, so if it is static, I cannot enforce that as we do with pure virtual functions. But let's say if I relax that requirement and make `getKeyStr()` static, can you elaborate on how we leverage `tuple` to do that?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I was thinking about UUID's, but the problem with that is we cannot customize the key-string, we only get whatever we get from the generator. In addition, the uuids won't be consistent in every run, which will break the key->type look up when we deserialize.

Comment: Issue with non static methods, is that several instances of the same class might return different values.

Comment: @Jarod42, no, the issue is not because different instances of the same class might return different values, but that we need to mandate an API getKeyStr() from every derived class plus we want to call that API through an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can have a list of all Derived classes, you might do something like:

```
template <typename... Ts>
bool have_unique_keys()
{
    std::string_view keys[] = {Ts{}.getKeyStr()...}; // requires constexpr default constructor
                                                     // static method might be more appropriate
    std::sort(std::begin(keys), std::end(keys)); // constexpr in C++20
    auto it = std::adjacent_find(std::begin(keys), std::end(keys));
    return it != std::end(keys);
}

static_assert(have_unique_keys<>(D1, D2, D3));
```

Comment: Looks promising, except that the derived class authors still need to follow the protocol of adding their classes to the static_assert line. BTW, is the have_unique_keys() signature missing the input arguments?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can check at compile time if the "strings" returned by `getKeyStr` of `D1`, and `D2` are different.

First provide a function that compares 2 `const char *` at compile time:

```
constexpr bool different(const char *x, const char *y)
{
  while(*x != '\0' )
    if (*x++ != *y++) return true;

  return *y != '\0'; 
}
```

and then compare the returned values:

```
// this will trigger, if returned strings are the same.
static_assert( different(D1{}.getKeyStr(), D2{}.getKeyStr()) );
```

Edit: As @Jarod42 points out, `string_view` comparison is `constexpr`, and so the comparison function can be written much more simply:

```
constexpr bool different(const char * x, const char * y)
{
    return std::string_view{x} != std::string_view{y};
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/VzLVFP).

Comment: That only enforces that two default-constructed values will return equal strings; it says nothing about them returning different for different objects. And if that weren't possible, why wouldn't the function be `static`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. It seems to me OP wants to be able to distinguish between the return values of virtual functions that are overridden by 2 classes. All calls would return the same value at compile time anyway.

Comment: "*All calls would return the same value at compile time anyway.*" No, they wouldn't. The functions could return a `const char*` value that they were given as a constructor parameter. That's perfectly valid in `constexpr` code. What the OP wants is wrong *because* these functions are member functions.

Comment: That's true, they could return different values. I'm not sure why OPs question is *wrong* though. Seems like a reasonable thing to want to do.

Comment: You need to write static_assert for each every pairs of derived classes you can possibly have. If you add a new derived class, then you have to write a bunch of static_assert against each every existing derived classes.

Comment: Absolutely, and solving that would be interesting. OP's question is precise about wanting to compare 2 derived classes, though.

Comment: There is already `std::string_view` which have `constexpr` comparison.

Comment: That's much nicer, I completely missed that. Thanks.